# change lablel text from a different class in same form

Tags: c#

I have one window from where I created one class.
I want to change the label text of window form from that class, but its not working.

here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    class clowder
    {
        public clowder()
        {
            label2.text="boject created ok done";
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        clowder c1 = new clowder();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What specifically are you trying to do, and what specifically is preventing you from doing it?

Comment: am asking how to change text of label at run time from any class.

Comment: By setting the `.Text` property on a reference to that label.  What happens when you *try*?  "It doesn't work" doesn't describe an actual problem.

Comment: yes i know label.text="hello"; but its not working when i write in class's method who have object in main

Comment: Try to understand that we can't actually see your screen from here.  You have to be specific about what "it's not working" means.  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected behavior?  If I were to *guess*, I suspect this would have a compile-time error indicating that `label2` doesn't exist in the current context.  But since your example is very much incomplete, that's just a guess.  If that guess is correct, I'd ask where you define `label2` and how that class is supposed to be referencing it?

Comment: oh yes sorry i forget to mention it gives error. label2 does not exist , while label2 is present on window form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label2` doesn't exist in that class.  You would need to pass a reference to it.  Something as simple as this would "work":

```
public clowder(Label label2)
{
    label2.Text = "boject created ok done";
}
```

And when invoking it:

```
clowder c1 = new clowder(this.label2);
```

***However***, this is kind of messy.

First of all, doing this *in a constructor* is a bad idea in general.  A constructor should simply construct an object, it shouldn't perform tasks.

Second, it's really best to keep your UI element references in the UI objects (in this case `Form` objects).  Instead of passing UI elements to business logic objects to modify those elements, get *values* from business logic objects and modify the UI elements *in the UI*.  Something more like this:

```
public class clowder
{
    public string SomeOperation()
    {
        return "boject created ok done";
    }
}
```

and in the form:

```
label2.Text = new clowder().SomeOperation();
```

Comment: if i do not want to return value from class for label2, then how i can change label2 from class without returning its value in main function ?

Comment: @hareemkhan: Exactly as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: its giving me invalid exception . Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'at' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @hareemkhan: Interesting. It's been a very long time since I've had to use WinForms, but I do recall some restrictions like this. All the more reason to use good design practices and not try to modify form elements outside of the form objects. Get the data you need from your logic classes, apply that data to the UI in your UI classes.